# Change the default template when New HTML Page is selected in VWD Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I change the template for the page that is created when a new HTML page is created in Visual Web Developer Express 2010?

I found a bunch of files in `c:/program files (x 86)/ Micorosft Visual Studio 10.0/Web/WebNewFileItems` including `HTMLPage.htm` which is the default name of the new file, but when I try to edit this file it doesn't save and says the file is in use, even if I switch off VWD. I tried creating a new file in another folder and overwriting the template file but that didn't work either!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The correct path you should go to for these changes to take affect is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\NewFileItems`

Comment: Doesn't work. I've edited the file there, and the changes I made are not applied. The original file at that location doesn't look the same as the new page that is created. VS2012 is the same btw...